# Automatically update Google Sheet sort column with checkboxes

Tags: google-sheets

I have a range of data on Google Sheets that I'd like to sort by different columns, for easier readability. I can select the data and sort manually by different columns, but this is something I need to do regularly, so I think it would be great to be able to check a box to automatically sort the range by a given column.

The data I'm using is sensitive so here's a really basic idea of what I mean:

[image]

I'd like to check the box under height to sort by height, then be able to select house number to automatically update to that range.

I realise this seems fairly convoluted and if there's a simpler way to achieve this (without the checkboxes) I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to sort by a column is to right-click the column label (`A`, `B`, `C`, `D`) and choose **Sort sheet A→Z**.

To prepare your sheet for sorting, choose **View > Freeze > Freeze 2 rows**.